# Displaying values from another model in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to this and have an easy question I'm sure. I have 2 models, customers (has many jobs) and jobs (belongs to customers). I have a view which displays job details. I want to select data from the customer, but am getting an error.

**Index action in jobs controller:**

`@jobs = Job.all` (NB have also tried `@jobs = Job.includes(:customer).all`)

**In my view:**

```
<% @jobs.each do |job| %>
  ...
  <td><% job.customer.surname %></td>`
```

But I get the following error:

```
undefined method `surname' for nil:NilClass
```

What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: Could you add the complete controller action please?

Comment: `customer` might be another model of yours. You are getting error because you are trying to access the attribute `surname` for `customer` which is nil. Either check if the `customer` is present by adding `if job.customer` or add validations to check every job has an associated customer.

Comment: Yes thanks guys, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although `Job` belongs to `Customer`, it's possible that a given `job.customer` may be `nil`!

First, you can check this in your view:

```
<% jobs.each do |job| %> 
  <% if job.customer.blank? %>
    <!-- debugging info: -->
    <p>Oops, this Job doesn't have a customer</p>
    <p>customer_id is <%= job.customer_id.inspect %>)</p>
  <% else %>
    <p><%= job.customer.surname %></p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

If it turns out that some `Job`s don't have `Customer`s, there might be something wrong in another part of the app. There are few possibilities:

- `jobs#create` is not assigning the customer to the job.

  To prevent this, edit `Job` and add `validates :customer, presence: true`.
- `job.customer_id` may contain an invalid foreign key (ie, `job.customer_id` is present, but there is no `Customer` whose `id` is `job.customer_id`).

  To prevent this, inside `Customer`, add `has_many :jobs, dependent: :destroy` to make
  sure that all jobs are destroyed when the customer is destroyed.